# javascript cannot stop audio recording

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the stopAudio() isn't stopping it, reporting it to be inactive, despite very clearly being active according to the recording dot at the favicon

```js
let recorder;
let audioChunks = [];
let mediaRecorder = null;
let audioPlayer = null;

function startAudio() {
  // stop any previous audio playback
  if (audioPlayer !== null) {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      const audio = document.createElement('audio');
      const chunks = [];
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
      });

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // create a new audio element and append it to the container
                document.getElementById('AudioContainer').innerHTML = "<audio src='"+audioUrl+"' controls='true' />";
                AudioClip = "<audio src='"+audioUrl+"' controls='true' />";
      });
    });
}
function stopAudio() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
}
```

Comment: Note that the "dot" is the media-device witness, it's completely unrelated to the MediaRecorder and means that one of your input devices is still active.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I forgot to add `mediaRecorder.start()`, probably from looking at too much code for the day